# VBScript - get main monitor resolution

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi, resolution

I need to get current **main** display resolution using VBScript.
Main display has start menu on it.

I've checked:

- Array of Win32_VideoSettings has 0 elements
- Array of Win32_VideoConfiguration has 0 elements
- Array of Win32_VideoController has always 1 element - even if there is second monitor plugged-in

How can I get resolution of the currently set **main** screen?

Answer (score 3):

```vb
'Author: Demon
'Website: http://demon.tw
'Date: 2012/5/7
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DesktopMonitor",,48)

For Each objItem in colItems
    WScript.Echo "ScreenHeight: " & objItem.ScreenHeight
    WScript.Echo "ScreenWidth: " & objItem.ScreenWidth
Next
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me